# Jquery on enter/keypress not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple search box that allows you to search  based on a keyword you enter in the input field. This work fine if you press the Submit button.

I would also like to be able to press the Enter or Return key to initiate the search. I've tried using the .on function it only seems to work for click  but no success on enter or keypress. 
Any insight would be greatly appreciate!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$("#gallery").empty();                          
    $("#submit").on("click keypress",function (e) {
                 console.log( $( this ).text() );
                 console.log("e.which " +e.which);
                 console.log("e.type " +e.type);

             if (e.which === 13 || e.type === 'click') {     
                if($("#term").val() !="" ){
                //$("#gallery").empty();    
                /**********************/
                updatestatus();
                ajaxProcess();
                /**************************/    
                }else {
                    //$("#gallery").text("Please enter a keyword to search").fadeOut(2500);
                    alert("Please enter a keyword to search");
                }
             }
    });

    $("#clear").click(function(){
            $("#gallery").empty();                 
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="" id="term" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Go">
<input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

Comment: So do you hit enter on the `#submit` button, or in the `#term` input? You should probably bind one event to each element.

Comment: Or even better, attach the event to the forms `submit` event, and it will work automagically

Comment: @user244394 I've shown example of both form submit as well as binding keypress event to input text box. Check my answer

Comment: You can have only one either submit or enter. Both will trigger same event @user244394

Answer (score 1):

Bind a `onsubmit` event handler to the form. So when you click on `enter` key in the input text, the form submit will trigger which will execute your ajax call.

```js
  $("#submit").on("click keypress",function (e) {
        
            if($("#term").val() !="" ){
            /*
            updatestatus();
            ajaxProcess();
            */
            }else {
                alert("Please enter a keyword to search");
            }
});

$("#clear").click(function(){
     $("#gallery").empty();                 
});

  $("form").submit(function(e){
              $("#submit").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input type="text" value="" id="term" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Go">
<input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

Or bind `keypress` event to the `input` text box and check for `event.which==13` to check if its enter key and do the process.

```js
  $("#submit").on("click keypress",function (e) {
        
            if($("#term").val() !="" ){
            /*
            updatestatus();
            ajaxProcess();
            */
            }else {
                alert("Please enter a keyword to search");
            }
});

$("#clear").click(function(){
        $("#gallery").empty();                 
});

   $("input#term").on("keypress", function(e){
  if (e.which === 13) {
      $("#submit").trigger('click');
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input type="text" value="" id="term" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Go">
<input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only binding the event handler to the #submit element. But keypress events are not raised on that element.

Instead you have to bind to the document:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13: // RETURN
            ... 
    }
}
```

In the handler function you can then check which key was pressed and act on it.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event to the form input field it self :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").on("click",function () {
      // After submit stuff:
      updatestatus();
      ajaxProcess();
  });

  $("form input").keypress(function(e){
      if (e.which === 13) {
          $("#submit").trigger('click');
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code idoes fire both the events 'click' and 'Key press' but the catch here is you have bound 'keypress' event with the submit button which will only fire on enter button and not the character or numeric keys so you either need to bind the keypress to the input type or the document itself to perform your operation and not the button type

Also the KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.

*Happy Coding*