# Javascript keyup enter not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have general algorithm for checking the national code in my country. Every code has 10 digits:

```
function Nationalcode(code)
{

  var L=code.length;

  if(L<8 || parseInt(code,10)==0) return false;
  code=('0000'+code).substr(L+4-10);
  if(parseInt(code.substr(3,6),10)==0) return false;
  var c=parseInt(code.substr(9,1),10);
  var s=0;
  for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
    s+=parseInt(code.substr(i,1),10)*(10-i);
  s=s%11;
  return (s<2 && c==s) || (s>=2 && c==(11-s));
return true;
}
```

It works well when I add the method and run this with @click="check":

```
check: function(){
  var c=document.getElementById("CodeM").value;
  if( checkCodeMeli(c))
    alert("true");
  else
    alert("fasle");
}
```

But I want to check automatically when user entered 10 digits:

```
<input type="text" v-model="nationalcode" id="CodeM" v-on:keyup.enter="queryForKeywords" v-on:keydown="queryForKeywords">

    queryForKeywords: function() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        var c=document.getElementById("CodeM").value;
        this.isActive = 'false';
        if (this.nationalcode.length == 9 ) {
            if( checkCodeMeli(c)){
                alert("true");
            }
            else{
                alert("false");
            }
        }
        else{

        }
      });
    },
```

### This method works with incorrect results. For example when I entered:

0011433876,
button:true,
auto:true,

---

0011433875:
button:false,
auto:true,

---

0011433874:
button:false,
auto:true,

---

all buttons answers with "correct", but only the first is correct.

Comment: Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459741/jquery-on-enter-keypress-not-working

Comment: why do you do check length by `this.nationalcode.length` and not `c.length`?

Comment: Another side question: Wy `if (this.nationalcode.length == 9 ) {`and not `if (this.nationalcode.length == 10 ) {`?

Comment: Because it doesn't matter. it want to count charcter string or int, not imprtant

Comment: please try print `c` on each example of click and key version